# Breadboard circuit with LED going through 2 circuits doesn't work as expected

Tags: led, gpiozero

I have the resistor, GPIO24, and the LED anode connected along the same row of a breadboard. The signal from GPIO24 works as expected, but any signal from GPIO23 is lost and the LED will not light. I don't know enough about circuits to debug this.[image]

This is the code I'm testing with, nothing happens for the first 6 seconds. It looks like nothing happens on GPIO23.

```
from gpiozero import LED


led23 = LED(23)
led24 = LED(24)

led23.blink(n=3, background=False)
led24.blink(n=3, background=False)
```

But for whatever reason this code works and lights the LED

```
from gpiozero import LED


led23 = LED(23)
led23.blink(n=3, background=False)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112994/discussion-on-question-by-brady-dean-breadboard-circuit-with-led-going-through-2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to the conclusion there was nothing wrong with my circuit (and yes, I am now putting a 220 resistor on each led), but the problem was in software. Gpiozero doesn't work as expected when the same led is connected to 2 circuits. More specifically, I cannot have an `LED` object on pin 23 and 24 at the same time. My workaround is to switch out these `LED` objects during runtime.

```
from gpiozero import LED

led = LED(24)  # ref to whichever led being used

def switch_brightness():
    if led.pin.number == 24:
        led.close()
        led = LED(23)
    else:
        led.close()
        led = LED(24)

# use led, call switch_brightness when necessary
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the Hi-Z option may not be available on RPi, perhaps try this alternate wiring arrangement:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7hrcz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work as is. I was still getting the behavior where one led wouldn't light. Probably for the same reason in the answer I just posted.

Comment: In the comments, you said, `I'm only allowed to use 1 resistor.`  What happened to that requirement?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to get back on that. It's ok to use more than 1. Instructions were written in such a way that we could use either a RPI or Arduino. I think the 1 resistor requirement had something to do with that idk

Comment: I'm glad you got this working - good for you! For future reference however you should know that **most** GPIO pins can be placed in a [high impedance state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-state_logic) - in other words, the device may be "HI", "LO" or "Hi-Z", aka ***tri-state***. I don't know `gpiozero`, but I do know how the hardware behaves. If what you've said about gpiozero is true, it seems this is a case of `the tail wagging the dog`! :)

Comment: I've been reading through the gpiozero source and essentially it's just a wrapper around `RPi.GPIO` and all the `LED` class does is call `RPi.GPIO.output` on the pin. I can't tell why it's not working without running through a debugger